# Compute the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

2) Consider rolling one fair six-sided die, so that $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, and $P(s) =
1/6$ for all $s \in S$. Let $X$ be the number showing on the die, so that $X(s) = s$ for $s \in S$.
Let $Y = X^2$. Compute the cumulative distribution function $F_Y (y) = P(Y \leq y)$, for all
$y \in R^1$. Verify explicitly that properties (a) through (d) of Theorem 2.5.2 are satisfied
by this function $F_Y$ .

This is theorem 2.5.2

Theorem 2.5.2 Let $F_X$ be the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$. Then

(a) $0 \leq F_X(x) \leq 1, \forall x$

(b) $F_X (x) ≤ F_X (y)$ whenever $x ≤ y$ (i.e., $F_X$ is increasing)

(c) $\lim_{x\to+\infty} F_X(x) = 1$

(d) $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F_X(x) = 0$

SOLUTION:

$$F_X(x) = $$

\begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 1 \\
      1/6 & 1\leq x < 4 \\
      2/6 & 4 \leq x < 9 \\
      3/6 & 9 \leq x < 16 \\
      4/6 & 16 \leq x < 25 \\
      5/6 & 25 \leq x < 36 \\
      1 & 36 \leq x
\end{cases}

Properties (a) and (b) follow by inspection. Properties (c) and (d) follow since $F_y(y) = 0$ for $y < 1$, and $F_y(y) = 1$ for $y > 36$

---

Could someone please explain this solution because I don't understand how they got $F_X(x)$.

Like for example, the first one is if $F(x < 1) = 0$. What is $x$?

Comment: I believe the right-hand side should be $y<1$, $1 \leq y < 4$, and so on.

Comment: Rolls of a die result in numbers $X$ that are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. So it is not possible to get a result that is 0 or smaller. Thus $F_X(0) = P(X \le 0)  = 0$ and $P(X < 1) = 0.$

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh, I get it thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a piecewise function, which has the form $g(x) =\begin{cases} a &:& x\in A\\ b &:& x\in B \\ &\vdots&\\ c &:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

The domain of function $g$ is partitioned into disjoint sets $A,B,$ et cetera, and the value held by $g$ varies according to which part contains the argument.

It means that when $x\in A$, then $g(x)$ has value of $a$, else when $x\in B$, then $g(x)$ has value $b$, and so forth, with $g(x)$ having value $c$ when no other part holds.

So when $x<1$ the cummulative distribution function has value $0$.

---

Remark: the solution is wrong, in that it should be $F_Y(y)$ rather than $F_X(x)$; a typographic error.   Just replace the letters to match the question.

$$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 
      0 &:& \qquad y < 1 \\
      1/6 &:& 1\leq y < 4 \\
      2/6 &:& 4 \leq y < 9 \\
      3/6 &:& 9 \leq y < 16 \\
      4/6 &:& 16 \leq y < 25 \\
      5/6 &:& 25 \leq y < 36 \\
      1 &:& 36 \leq y
\end{cases}$$